# Is immutably modifying the action passed to sub-reducers unidiomatic?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm in a situation where a sub-reducer needs to know a small bit of data from its parent state when updating its own sub-state. Is it a good idea to pass a different action to a sub-reducer than the one the parent reducer was invoked with?

To be clear, I'm not talking about mutating the original action, I would create a new one that was slightly modified to add the extra data. The Redux docs say to not mutate the action, but nothing about passing down different actions.

So an example would be an action called `ADD_TO_CURRENT_INDEX` is passed to the root reducer, which stores an array and the "current" index. Is it okay to send a new action `ADD_TO_THIS_SPECIFIC_INDEX` to the sub-reducer for the array since we know the current index at this level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is certainly a bit unusual, but it's valid as far as I can tell.  The root reducer function as a whole needs to obey the basic reducer rules of `(state, action) -> newState` and immutable data updates, but Redux doesn't care how the internals of your reducer function are actually implemented.  If you want to handle a certain scenario by calling another function and passing in a "new" action rather than the actual action being dispatched, that should be fine as long as the behavior is consistent and repeatable overall.

Answer (score -1):

You can just handle that action type in your sub-reducer. (Did I misunderstand your question?)

If you want to dispatch an action within a reducer function, that would cause errors. See details [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/368)

**Update**: You cannot dispatch an action in a reducer function. But you can dispatch multiples action from you action creators by using middlewares like `redux-thunk`.

So instead of dispatch an action from one reducer to its sub-reducer, you can dispatch these actions all together from a thunk. and the information you need from the parent reducer can be re-calculated and be part of the action payload.

Also, if a piece a state can be directly derived from another piece, you may want to re-think about the design of your state tree.

Comment: Sorry, not quite. I meant if like, a reducer receives an action like ADD_TO_CURRENT_INDEX and reads what the current index is from the previous state, and then passes a new action ADD_INDEX with the current index in the payload to the sub-reducer (while other sub-reducers get the original index).

Comment: @RahatAhmed see update. Basically you can easily achieve what you want with `redux-thunk`, you don't need the ability to dispatch action inside a reducer function

Comment: I'm still not talking about dispatching actions at all. I'm talking about passing an action to a sub-reducer as its argument.